# How can I use the active GitHub-session in another tab

Tags: authentication, github

my question is nothing more than in the title. I want to build a web application which displays the repositories from a GitHub-classroom. But at the moment I can not load them since they are private. So I need to authenticate the web-application with GitHub.

Comment: I do not care if you have a solution for Spring, Node, Flask, or something else. Anything will help me

Comment: you can use [Oauth app](https://developer.github.com/apps/building-oauth-apps/) with [this flow](https://developer.github.com/apps/building-oauth-apps/authorizing-oauth-apps/)